# Ruler Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I created a ruler that looks like a typical ruler in school. What i want to know is, what kind of formula is this "int size = (i%2.5==0) ? 2000 : 13;".
I have successfully solved in creating this view but i don't really know how this formula works. Can anyone explain?

[image]

```
public class ColorRulerView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    static final private float pxinch = 500 / 67.f * 25.4f / 16;
    float width, height;

    public ColorRulerView(Context context, AttributeSet foo) {
        super(context, foo);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setAntiAlias(false);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
            float x = i * pxinch;
            if (x > 5000) {
                break;
            }
            int size = (i%2.5==0) ? 2000 : 13;
            c.drawLine(x, 2, x, size, paint);
        }
        super.onDraw(c);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I used this code but i did not get any UI.can you please help me

Comment: Hi @Ashish Agrawal. It's not including the color gradient, only the ruler stripes. You can use the stripes in your layout. Just add the line below in your layout. <com.blah.blah.ColorRulerView android:layout:width="100dp" android:layout:height="100dp"/>.

Comment: what is 500 and 16 (pxinch = 500 / 67.f * 25.4f / 16) in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
int size = (i%2.5==0) ? 2000 : 13
```

is a [ternary](http://Java%20ternary%20examples) operation.

lets break this down:

`(i % 2.5)` : this will produce the reminder when the value of **i** is divided by 2.5. So, if

**i** = 3, 3 % 2.5 =  0.5

**i** = 4, 4 % 2.5 = 1.5

assume **i** = 3, the result is 0.5 which is not equal to 0. So, size will be 13.

whenever the condition `(i % 2.5 == 0)` is `true`, size is assigned a value 2000 `else`, it is assign 13.

value that can make this condition `true` are *5, 10, 15* etc.

Comment: hi belvi. I got it. Nice formula to work. Thanks man, you are quick

Answer (score 0):

@donmj
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342096/confused-by-this-crash-log?noredirect=1#comment70539863_41342096

I have resolved this crash. I create a popupWindow in a fragment which has a transparent background, when I touch the background, I code to dismiss the popupWindow, however...it crashes. My code for the touch event is :

```
 background.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener{

   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
      popupWindow.dismiss;
      return true;
   }

 });
```

I modify my code to:

```
 background.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{

    public void onClick(View v){
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
})
```

Everything has done. Probably we have to study the touch event system for more details...TAT